# Debugging python tests in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

We want to debug Python tests in TensorFlow such as *sparse_split_op_test* and *string_to_hash_bucket_op_test*

The other c++ tests we could debug using gdb, however we cannot find a way to debug python tests.

Is there a way in which we can debug specific python test case run via Bazel test command (for example, bazel test //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_split_op_test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first build the test:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_split_op_test
```

Then use pdb on the resulting Python binary:

```
pdb bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/sparse_split_op_test
```

That seems to work for me stepping through the first few lines of the test.

Comment: Don't forget to re-build the file every time you make a change.

Comment: Fair point. More recently I've just been inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and using `bazel run`, which keeps everything up to date. `bazel test` gets in the way of the REPL.

Comment: doesn't work if you're referencing `$TEST_TMPDIR` in your tests.