# How to use PDB when using the "bazel test"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, bazel

I create a python unit test using unittest.TestCase. I have been using bazel in the project. The following is a simplified example.

```
py_library(
    name = "example",
    srcs = [ 
        "example.py"
    ],     
)

py_test(
    name = "example_test",
    srcs = [ 
        "example_test.py",
    ], 
    deps = [
        ":example", 
    ],    
)
```

The following command works well:

```
bazel test :example_test
```

But I would like to debug 'example.py' using 'pdb'.
If I add  the 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' line somewhere in example.py, 'bazel test' crashes with the following error message.

```
 if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit

bdb.BdbQuit
```

I did some search in the stackoveflow, but the following answer also doesn't work:

[Can I use Python Debugger In Bazel Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709590/can-i-use-python-debugger-in-bazel-test)

Could anyone give some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to run `bazel test` with pdb. But you can run the tests via `bazel run` as if they were a `py_binary` target and pdb works as usual.